Set PiZero's startup usb mode
I have a USB expansion hat connected and if I plug in a usb kbd and mouse receiver into the hat and pi is connected via power usb everything works as expected - mou and kbd control the pi and no device is open on host PC.
However if I plug the pi in via usb port then kbd and mou output control my host PC instead of the pi and the pi describes itself as the usb receiver(forwarding its reports and descriptors).
And so my question is how would I set the pi up in such way that when connected via usb port to the host pc it isn't anything(or it represents itself as a device that does nothing) and the mou and kbd control the pi but it still gives me an option of eventually switching it to some device for example like raw-gadget lib lets you on my pi4.
